# Split Nagios configuration into multiple files

Tags: file, configuration, split, nagios

NagiosQL creates a file called servicetemplates.cfg.
For easier distribution of some selected templates I' d like to split any service definition into one seperate file.
Sample servicetemplates.cfg

```
define service {
   name                                     imap_service
   use                                      generic_service
   check_command                            check_service_imap
   register                                 0
}

define service {
       name                                     ldapserver_ldap_service
       service_description                      LDAP
       use                                      generic_service
       check_command                            check_service_ldap
       icon_image                               ldapserver.png
       register                                 0

}
```

What I like to have is some kind of parser, which create files like the "name" of the template, e. g. imap_service.cfg and ldapserver_ldap_service.cfg.
Every file have to include the whole definition (define service { ... } )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following code is a solution for me, it might not be perfect as it expects a certain syntax of the Nagios object configuration.
The first parameter has to be the file name of the Nagios configuration file.

```
<?php
if (empty($argv[1])) {
        echo "First parameter: File to Nagios object configuration\n";
        exit(1);
}

$starttag=0;
$outfile='';
$outtext='';
$inputfile=$argv[1];
$cfgfile = file($inputfile) or exit(2);

foreach ($cfgfile as $line_num => $line) {
        # $outtext will be reset if define ... { is found
        $outtext.=$line;
        # Start tag of a new section "define ... {"
        if (preg_match("/.*define.*{/i", $line)) {
                $starttag=1;
                $outtext=$line;
        }
        # Split the line with name. The parameter after name is the later filename
        if (preg_match("/name[\s]+[\w]+/", $line) && $starttag=1) {
                $keywords=preg_split("/[\s]+/", $line);
                $outfile=$keywords[2];
                $outfile.=".cfg";
                $outfile=str_replace(' ', '_', $outfile);
        }
        # End tag of a new section "}"
        if (preg_match("/.*}/", $line) && $starttag=1) {
                $starttag=0;
                echo "Writing {$outfile}\n";
                file_put_contents($outfile, $outtext);
        }
}

echo "Read lines {$line_num} from {$inputfile}\n";
?>
```